# How to get image name to delete from file pond react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, filepond

I am using [React Filepond](https://github.com/pqina/react-filepond) to upload an image to a node.js server which uses Multer. The upload works fine but when I try to undo (delete) the upload straight after uploading I get a 404 error.

```
    <FilePond
      ref={ref => (this.pond = ref)}
      files={this.state.files}
      allowMultiple={false}
      maxFiles={1}
      name="photo"
      server={{ url: "http://localhost:8000/api/uploads/", revert: "http://localhost:8000/api/revert/" }}
      oninit={() => this.handleInit()}
      onupdatefiles={fileItems => {
        // Set currently active file objects to this.state
        this.setState({
          files: fileItems.map(fileItem => fileItem.file)
        });
      }}
    />
```

This is probably because it can't find the file name. On the node side of things I set the filename like this:

```
const multerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "public/img");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const ext = file.mimetype.split("/")[1];
    cb(null, `hero-${Date.now()}.${ext}`);
  }
});
```

Which gives me:

hero-1564944240035

Now, when I try to delete that, I get the 404. If I try to create that name again, the timestamp will be different. What would be the best way to get that exact file name in order for the delete to work?

Comment: Are you returning the file name to FilePond in the response to the upload call?

Comment: @Rik, are you referring to the 200 response from node.js? `exports.updateHeroImg = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file.originalname);
  res.status(200).send("Upload success");
};`

Comment: Yes, the response should be the file id, see https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/